# Excel stating it is unsafe?

Tags: microsoft-excel

On opening Excel-files I get this nowadays.

[image]

Is there anyone out there that has an idea on HOW to determine EXACTLY WHAT it is about (as it doesn't say).

And most importantly: Is there some way to avoid this nuisance?

*Note: This is on opening the Excel-files I personally have created, which contain "helper functions" written in VBA.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what the sheet is connected to, go to the `Data` tab on the ribbon bar, and then click on `Edit Links`.

[image]

The dialogue box will show you what type of connection exists, and to what.

To suppress the pop-up, click `Startup Prompt...` on the `Edit Links` dialogue, and choose an appropriate option.

[image]

[image]

If you want to disassociate the links, select the appropriate link from the list, and click `Break Link`

Comment: Thanks: this pinpoints the "base"(main) Excel-file which store my macros, which get used from other files. Apparently this structure is a "problem" (i.e. with macros external to a certain file) .

Comment: Yes, sounds that way. I would therefore suppress the message, if it's becoming an irritant.

Comment: "Me too", so Done.